# Are there “nice” explicit representations of infinite order elements in $\pi_{4n-1}(S^{2n})$

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, hopf-fibration

Motivation:

- The representation is very clean in the Hopf fibration case (2n=2,4,8).
- These maps are known since Serre's 1951 paper.
- There are clean generators for the only other infinite case $\pi_n(S^n)$.

Comment: This is well answered here :) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402623/is-there-a-concrete-description-of-the-nontorsion-elements-in-the-homotopy-group

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write an explicit formula as follows.  Consider a pair of finite-dimensional inner product spaces $U$ and $V$.  We can define a map
$$ f\colon S(U\oplus V) \to S(U\oplus\mathbb{R})\vee S(V\oplus\mathbb{R}) $$
by
$$ f(u,v) = \begin{cases}
 \left(2\sqrt{\|v\|^2-\|u\|^2}\;u,\;2\|u\|^2-\|v\|^2\right)/\|v\|^2 
  \in S(U\oplus\mathbb{R}) & \text{ if } \|u\|\leq\|v\| \\
 \left(2\sqrt{\|u\|^2-\|v\|^2}\;v,\;2\|v\|^2-\|u\|^2\right)/\|u\|^2 
  \in S(V\oplus\mathbb{R}) & \text{ if } \|u\|\geq\|v\|
\end{cases} $$
The two clauses are consistent because they both give the basepoint $(0,1)$ when $\|u\|=\|v\|$.  It is an algebraic exercise to check that both clauses give a unit vector in the indicated space.  Further formulae that I will not give here identify the cofibre of $f$ with $S(U\oplus\mathbb{R})\times S(V\oplus\mathbb{R})$, which shows that $f$ is the attaching map for the top cell of this product.  It is also interesting to identify the fibres of $f$.  For any point $(x,t)\in S(U\oplus\mathbb{R})$ that is not equal to $(0,1)$, we can define
$g_{(x,t)}\colon S(V)\to U\oplus V$ by
$$ g_{(x,t)}(v) = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{(1-t)(3+t)}},\sqrt{\frac{2}{3+t}}v \right). $$
One can check that this lands in $S(U\oplus V)$ and gives a homeomorphism $S(V)\to f^{-1}\{(x,t)\}$.  Similarly, the fibre of $f$ over any non-basepoint in $S(V\oplus\mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to $S(U)$.

Now take $V=U=\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and compose $f$ with the fold map $S(U\oplus\mathbb{R})\vee S(U\oplus\mathbb{R})\to S(U\oplus\mathbb{R})$ to get a map
$$ h\colon S^{4n-1} = S(U\oplus U) \to S(U\oplus\mathbb{R}) = S^{2n}. $$
This is a representative of the usual Whitehead homotopy class.

Comment: Isn’t there a sign issue, as well as the connecting point being 1, 0 ant not 0, 1 ?